# Elegant algorithm to control max value for carousel

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a slider which at most can show 3 elements. If there are more elements, these are hidden and

can come into view by clicking left right as following image.

[image]

This slider will be taking in a position prop. Note that I can't change this component which is external.

```
<Slider position={position} />
```

The position value decide the red position as shown in following image.

[image]

I am trying to have an algorithm to set this position with following rules.

If the elements are 3 or less, position should always be 0.

Anything more, it should not slide past the last element.

Meaning let's say I pass in the value 4 (so index 4, 5th element) for the position value, the component will look like the following.

[image]

Above is wrong. It should look like the following where it filled 3 spots while still sliding to the left as much as possible.

Thus it would have worked fine if I passed in the position value as 2.

[image]

Also to use position value as is if acceptable without needing to modify it as follows.

[image]

Looking for algorithm that will:

Get a position value and decide if it can be used as is or need to amend based on element count and the max visible elements which is 3.
And obtain a modified position value and pass it to the Slider component.

Was thinking something along the line of the following.

Based on testing, believe this work. Looking for validation if this would work.

And advice if there is a way I could make this more elegant and possibly not have

the initial if check for the less than or equals 3 elements.

```
// elementCount = // dynamic count of elements.
// initialPosition = // initial position being passed in which needs to be validated.
const getPosition = (elementCount, initialPosition) => {
    if (elementCount <= 3) {
        return 0;
    }
    const maxPosition = elementCount - 3;
    return initialPosition <= maxPosition ? initialPosition : maxPosition;
}
```

Note: This is essentially a React project but didn't tag it as so considering the query is more algorithm related. Thanks.

Comment: `Math.max(0, Math.min(initalPosition, elementCount - 3))`?

Comment: @Bergi This looks perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need a better abstraction. You need a circular list of image elements regardless howmany of them you have in the array and you shouldn't care about the end whatsoever. Such as, when  you have depleted the images, the one at the very front or end, depending on the direction of scroll, should take place. Perhaps you can modify [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/132397/105433) for your case.

Comment: @Redu Thanks. Does make sense but we are meant to stop it from going circular as per the requirements.

Comment: I recommend that @Bergi should post that expression as an answer, and karvai should accept it as the answer.